# How to override system.xml core file in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0, magento-2.0.7

I would like to change **New order status** text to something else at payment method section of magento2 admin.

```
Admin->Store->Configuration->Sales->Payment method->Check / Money Order
```

See attachment for better reference.

[image]

I know that i can change this by core changes but i would like to change this text without making any change in core file.

I am able to do this by editing system.xml

```
vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/etc/adminhtml/system.xml
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Magento may load our custom system config and merge into the exist nodes.
In our custom system config, we should try:

#### Tested on Magento 2.0.2 and 2.1.2

*Vendor/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/system.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment">
            <group id="checkmo">
                <field id="order_status" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Custom New Order Status</label> <!-- Custom label -->
                </field>  
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Remember to add overridden module - `Magento_OfflinePayments`

*Vendor/ModuleName/etc/module.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_YourModule" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_OfflinePayments"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: This works. System.xml should live in `Vendor/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`.

Comment: @MatHellums I updated my answer properly.

Comment: I tried your solution. but it doesn't helped me. Do i need to run any additional command?

Comment: @MakwanaKetan which is your Magento version?

Comment: Thats correct answer. there was issue with my custom module itself. I accepted your answer. thanks

Comment: This did not work (even though my <sequence> stuff was correct) and the module name was Exxx_Xxxxx. When modifying the order, so the module loaded last, in config.php everything worked fine... Magento 2.1.7...

Comment: @Robban You should create a new question about your current issue. I will take a look.

Comment: this solution not working

Comment: magento version 2.2.6 . Solution is not working

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh , how to add new field to any system.xml using above method ?

Comment: @Seefan add field in Vendor/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/system.xml 

<field id="order_custom" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
          <label>Custom Field</label> <!-- Custom field -->
 </field>